# Setting setFormulas() will clear the existing data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to keep the cell data as it is for those cells which have no formula applied.

The code snippet explains the function.

this solution too overwrites the values, [setFormulas won't skip empty array elements, over-writes values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131491/setformulas-wont-skip-empty-array-elements-over-writes-values)

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var Formulas = range.getFormulas();


for (var i in Formulas) {
    for (var j in Formulas[i]) {

        if (Formulas[i][j] == "") //cells which dont have the formula
        {
            //dont apply any formula, but keep the existing cell data (as it is)
        } else {
            Formulas[i][j] = '=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com","Google")'
        }
    }
}

range.setFormulas(Formulas);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"copyTo()" can copy cells with values, formulas and format. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)

Sample script is as follows.

**Script :**

```
var range = ss.getRange('a1:a8');
var values = range.getValues();
var formulas = range.getFormulas();

var destrange = ss.getRange('b1:b8');
range.copyTo(destrange);

var destvalues = destrange.getValues();
var destformulas = destrange.getFormulas();
```

**values :**

```
[[1.0], [5.0], [3.0], [9.0], [1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [24.0]]
```

**formulas :**

```
[[], [], [], [=sum(A1:A3)], [], [], [], [=sum(A1:A7)]]
```

**destvalues :**

```
[[1.0], [5.0], [3.0], [9.0], [1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [24.0]]
```

**destformulas :**

```
[[], [], [], [=sum(B1:B3)], [], [], [], [=sum(B1:B7)]]
```

If this will be helpful for you, I'm glad.